# django celery worker keyword argument error

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I'm trying to setup a simple webhook where incoming request are processed by a celery worker.

That's my the hook in the `view.py`:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class SendGridCallbackView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('TEST')
        req_dict = {'request': request.body}
        sendgrid_email_tracking.apply_async(kwargs=req_dict)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The task defined in `tasks.py`:

```
@shared_task(base=WorkerBase, name='mailer.sendgrid-tracking-mail')
def sendgrid_email_tracking(**kwargs):
    print('GOTCHA')
```

When sending a test email from sendgrid it prints the `TEST` output but then the celery worker returns an error

```
TypeError: sendgrid_email_tracking() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

When I add an additional argument `*args` then the error disappears, but on the called method both `*args` and `**kwargs` are empty

```
@shared_task(base=WorkerBase, name='mailer.sendgrid-tracking-mail')
def sendgrid_email_tracking(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)     # prints -> ()
    print(kwargs)   # prints -> {}
```

Comment: Hi, Though not a solution but can you try `sendgrid_email_tracking.delay('request'=request.body)`, as this is also another way to call the apply_async function

Comment: That doesn't even compile...

Comment: what is the error

Comment: `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please try this `sendgrid_email_tracking.delay(request=request.body)` Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the same error again `TypeError: sendgrid_email_tracking() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`

Comment: Try argument to tasks as `*args, **kwargs`

Comment: I updated the question for the additional argument `args`; then the error disappears but both arguments are empty!?

Comment: Just to be completely sure, if you try `print(kwargs['request'])` presumably you get a `KeyError`?

Comment: Yes I do get the key error since the dict is empty